# Как запросом показать список файловых групп базы данных?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как для заданной базы данных запросом показать ее список файловых групп?
Сервер баз данных Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Какой движок SQL? Реализация файловых групп зависит от сервера.

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: За что минусуем и закрываем? По-моему все просто и прямолинейно.

Answer (score 1):

Как ни странно, довольно просто.

```
use <database_name>;
select * from sys.filegroups where type="FG";
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно